# Accessing variables in flutter build. Gradle from azure pipeline

Tags: android, flutter, azure-pipelines, build.gradle

Have created key store config varibales in azure pipeline and trying to access it in build.gradle using System.getenv('keyAlias')

On printing the same, getting null in azure pipeline logs and hence build failing,

Using classic pipeline setup and running flutter build appbundle --release to generate a signed app bundle
What should be done in order to resolve this

Tried accessing using System.getenv, getting null

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.